# Android:How to run i-jetty web server on android 2.2 froyo os enabled tablet pc?

Tags: android, tablet-pc

My question is: I am using android 2.2 froyo os enabled tablet pc, I installed "i-jetty 2.2" web server on tablet pc,it's running perfectly fine but I can't see it's home page on the browser.It is showing **ERROR:503** service unavailable.

Any clue about this problem would be a great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in your i-jetty log?

Comment: there is no error in console/log of the server.

Answer (score 2):

To get an error 503, some webserver responded to your request saying that the web server is alive, but nothing is being handled/served right now (not even a 404 not found).

It could have been i-jetty, or it could have been a mobile provider's big-web-proxy-in-the-sky preventing you from getting to the device (that is if you are using the tablet on a mobile network)

If you can get the response headers out from the error 503, you can tell if it was i-jetty or some other server responding to you. Look for the header "Server:".